# What are the pads without holes on perfboard for

Tags: soldering, protoboard

So I bought a 10 pack of 4 x 6 cm perfboard. On two ends there is a row of pads without holes:
[image: Perfboard with pads]
What are they used for?

Comment: Like with any perfboard, they are for whatever you use them for. I use them for thicker wires that dont fit the holes

Comment: You can tack SMD components to them. You can "edge mount" a 0.100" header to the board, or sometimes even a 2-row D-sub connector, if you're a bit creative.

Comment: [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) is free to download, use and modify. It can be used to crop bad photos and make them suitable for presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use them for edge-mounted strips of LEDs.
They might also fit a card-edge connector, although they are rather short for that.
They could also be used for edge-mount header strips.